# Abaqus aborts script in command prompt - IndexError: -1

Tags: python

I get the error `IndexError: -1`

I'm trying to run a Python script in command prompt. When I run it through Abaqus CAE, it works. When I try run using command prompt without GUI i get the error.

I am able to complete the job, but my script also opens the output database. It is at this step error appears.

I've tried googling it, but  I didn't get any smarter. What does this generally mean in Python? And why does my script work in abaqus, but only halfway through command prompt?

Thank you!

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import time, os
from abaqus import *
from part import *
from material import *
from section import *
from assembly import *
from step import *
from interaction import *
from load import *
from mesh import *
from job import *
from sketch import *
from visualization import *
from connectorBehavior import *
from odbAccess import *


mdb = openMdb(pathName='X:\MinPreload-VaryingBC')
modelName = 'minPreload'
cMdb = mdb.models[modelName]

date = strftime("%Y-%d-%b", gmtime())

logPath_bu = 'C:\Users\yyt\maxMin-%s.txt' %date
logObj_bu = open(logPath_bu, 'a')
TopOfThePage = 'JobName\tCFNM at Preload\tTime Finished\tPreload\n\n'
logObj_bu.write(TopOfThePage)
logObj_bu.close()


output = open('C:\yyt\Output-%s.txt' %date, 'a')
output.write('Job \t\t\t'+'PS723\t\t'+'PS721\t\t'+'PL\t\t'+'FRIC\n\n')
output.close()


jobName = ""
maxCf = 0.0

#Temperature
minTemp = -49
maxTemp = 101
temperature = [minTemp, maxTemp]
bcTemp = 'Temperature'

#Friction
friction = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0,3, 0.4, 0,4, 0.5, 0.5]
interactionProperty = 'Contact Seal Coupler'

#PressureSwitcher
Pressure = True

internalPressure = 76
cMdb.loads['IP'].resume('Pressure')
internalPressBC = cMdb.loads['IP']
setInternalPressureBC = internalPressBC.setValues(magnitude=internalPressure)

externalPressure = 33
cMdb.loads['ExtP'].resume('Pressure')
externalPressBC = cMdb.loads['ExtP']
setExternalPressureBC = externalPressBC.setValues(magnitude=externalPressure)

# Preload

adjustedPreload = 0

PLipht = 10
PLiplt = 10
PLextpht = 10
PLextplt = 10

for temp in temperature:

    output = open('C:\yyt\Output-%s.txt' %date, 'a')
    output.write('\n')
    output.close()

    tempBC = cMdb.boundaryConditions[bcTemp]
    setTemp = tempBC.setValues(magnitude=temp)
    if temp == minTemp:
        adjustedPreload = 0.10315
    else:
        adjustedPreload = -0.21288

    for fric in friction:
        tangProp =  cMdb.interactionProperties[interactionProperty].tangentialBehavior
        tangProp.setValues(table=((fric,),))

        if Pressure:
            cMdb.loads['IP'].resume('Pressure')
            cMdb.loads['ExtP'].suppress('Pressure')
            press = 'IP'

        else:
            cMdb.loads['ExtP'].resume('Pressure')
            cMdb.loads['IP'].suppress('Pressure')
            press = 'ExtP'


        if temp == maxTemp and Pressure:
            PLi = PLipht
        elif temp == minTemp and Pressure:
            PLi = PLiplt
        elif temp == maxTemp and Pressure:
            PLi = PLextpht
        elif temp == minTemp and Pressure:
            PLi = PLextplt

        for PL in range (PLi, 100):
            axPL = float(PL)/100
            preloadBC = cMdb.boundaryConditions['axial_move']
            setPreloadBC = preloadBC.setValuesInStep('Pre', u2=axPL)

            clampBC = cMdb.boundaryConditions['clamp']

            modifyBottomCoupler = clampBC.setValuesInStep('Temp', -adjustedPreload )
            setPreloadBC = preloadBC.setValuesInStep('Temp', u2=(axPL+adjustedPreload))


            #Create a job

            fricInt = fric*10
            jobName = date + '_%dC-0_%df-%s-0_%dPLl' %(temp, fricInt, press, PL)


            mdb.Job(model=modelName, name=jobName)

            #submit Job

            mdb.jobs[jobName].submit(consistencyChecking=OFF)

            #Wait for job to complete

            status = str(mdb.jobs[jobName].messages[-1].type)

            mdb.jobs[jobName].waitForCompletion()


            #Collect data from job
            lastStepName = 'Pressure'

            odb = session.openOdb(name=jobName+'.odb')
            region = odb.steps[lastStepName].historyRegions['NodeSet  Z000002']
            region2 = odb.steps[lastStepName].historyRegions['NodeSet  Z000001']

            CFNM1 = region.historyOutputs['CFNM     ASSEMBLY_SLAVEBOT/ASSEMBLY_MASTERBOT'].data
            CFNM2 = region2.historyOutputs['CFNM     ASSEMBLY_SLAVESURFTOP/ASSEMBLY_MASTERTOP'].data

            for i, var in enumerate(CFNM1):
                if i == len(CFNM1) - 1:
                    maxCf1 = var[-1]
                    print str(maxCf1) + 'CFNM1 724/723'


            for i, var in enumerate(CFNM2):
                if i == len(CFNM2) - 1:
                    maxCf2 = var[-1]
                    print str(maxCf2) + 'CFNM2 722/721'


            output = open('C:\yyt\Output-%s.txt' %date, 'a')
            output.write(jobName+'\t\t'+str(maxCf1)+'\t\t'+str(maxCf2)+'\t\t'+'0.'+str(PL)+'\t\t'+str(fric)+'\n')
            output.close()


            if maxCf1 >= 10000 and maxCf2 >= 10000:

                time_done = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())

                logObj_bu = open(logPath_bu, 'a')
                logObj_bu.write(jobName+'\t'+'  CFNM1 = ' + str(maxCf1)+'  CFNM2 = ' + str(maxCf2)+'\t' + time_done + '%d\n\n' %PL)

                logObj_bu.close()

                Pressure = not Pressure

                if temp == maxTemp and Pressure:
                    PLipht = axPL-0.02
                elif temp == minTemp and Pressure:
                    PLiplt = axPL-0.02
                elif temp == maxTemp and Pressure:
                    PLextpht = axPL-0.02
                elif temp == minTemp and Pressure:
                    PLextplt = axPL-0.02


                break
```

What I get

```
End Abaqus/Standard Analysis
Abaqus JOB 2014-06-Mar_-49C-0_1f-IP-0_10PLl COMPLETED
IndexError: -1

Abaqus Error: cae exited with an error.
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError

Comment: It's hard to help, when you don't show any code or traceback messages.

Comment: @jcfollower Hi! I added the code now. I'm not quite sure where the problem is, so I added it all.

Comment: Please add the traceback as well. It will include references to the line and code that triggered the error.

Comment: @jcfollower 

Actually, this is all I get:

End Abaqus/Standard Analysis
Abaqus JOB 2014-06-Mar_-49C-0_1f-IP-0_10PLl COMPLETED
IndexError: -1

Abaqus Error: cae exited with an error.

Comment: Just a thought ... could it be the `print` statements?

Comment: Another thought ... you re-open the same files more than once.  I wonder if there is a timing issue where you try to re-open a file before the system finishes closing it.  (Can't you wait to close them until the end?)

Answer (score 1):

You have three potential pitfalls concerning the **IndexError: -1**

```
            [...]

            status = str(mdb.jobs[jobName].messages[-1].type)

            [...]

            for i, var in enumerate(CFNM1):
                if i == len(CFNM1) - 1:
                    maxCf1 = var[-1]
                    print str(maxCf1) + 'CFNM1 724/723'


            for i, var in enumerate(CFNM2):
                if i == len(CFNM2) - 1:
                    maxCf2 = var[-1]
                    print str(maxCf2) + 'CFNM2 722/721'

            [...]
```

The *IndexError* itself indicates, that you are trying to access an elment of a list or sequence, which is out of range. Since you are using an index of *-1*, you want to access the last element of the list or sequence, so you should check for none emptiness before accessing any element, e.g.:

```
            [...]

            for i, var in enumerate(CFNM2):
                if i == len(CFNM2) - 1 and var:
                    maxCf2 = var[-1]
                    print str(maxCf2) + 'CFNM2 722/721'

            [...]
```

*Note the `and var` at the end of the if clause.*

Comment: Could you please expand on what you do here? I'm not sure I follow.